# Backbone sort method

Tags: sorting, backbone.js, collections

I have the following code :

```
Campaign.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({initialize: function() {
},
comparator: function(item) { return item.get('Name'); }
}
```

I call collection.sort() and seems to work and sorts models regarding Name field the problem is that gives higher priority to uppercase letters example ('Some test' < 'more test') is there a way to override the behavior ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest fix is to simply do the following:

```
Campaign.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {},
    comparator: function(item) { return item.get('Name').toLowerCase(); }
};
```

This will convert all to lower case before comparing so it will compare in a manner that ignores case.

Answer (score 6):

For a case insensitive comparison, use the native JS function `toLowerCase`:

```
Campaign.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({initialize: function() {
},
comparator: function(item) { return item.get('Name').toLowerCase(); }
}
```